# MongoDB :: Can I Map a Document with a Text String?

Tags: mongodb, import, map-function

I'm using MongoDB for the first time (running on the latest Docker Container, MongoDB ver is 5.0.8).  I have several thousand JSON files that I'd like to import into a MongoDB collection, but I'd also like to map a unique text string to each imported document.  Each file contains exactly one document.

In researching this, I was hoping to find some command line solution, something like:

```
mongoimport --db "db01" --collection "table01" --file "document01.json"  --map "String01"
mongoimport --db "db01" --collection "table01" --file "document02.json"  --map "String02"
mongoimport --db "db01" --collection "table01" --file "document03.json"  --map "String03"
...etc...
```

But of course, `mongoimport` doesn't support a `--map` option.

Is there some way to do this?  I should also note that every JSON document is unique and its corresponding String will also be unique.  `document01.json` would only ever map to `String01` and `String01` would only be mapped to 'document01.json`.  The idea is that if I have a document, I could look up the string, and vice versa.  (I know that by default, every document will have a` _id`field, but I can't use that for my purposes, because my external code can't know the value of`_id` in advance.)  Thank you.

## UPDATE:

A user requested to see two toy examples.  Suppose I had this JSON document, stored in a file:

```
{
    "Starship": "USS Enterprise",
    "Crew": {
        "captain": "Kirk",
        "firstOfficer": "Spock",
        "medicalOfficer": "McCoy"
    }
}
```

I would want that document to be mapped to string "`ListOfSTCharacters`".  Then, later, while I'm sorting through my data, if I search for "`ListOfSTCharacters`", this document would come up.  Alternately, if I find this document, I should be able to pull up the string.

The JSON documents/files may each have entirely different structures.  This might be the second document to be imported into MongoDB:

```
ListOfSTActors
{
    "Series": "Original Series",
    "Network":  "NBC",
    "Cast": {
        "Kirk": "William Shatner",
        "Spock": "Leonard Nimoy",
        "McCoy": "DeForest Kelly"
    },
    "Rating": "Pretty good!"
}
```

That document should be mapped to string "`ListOfSTActors`".  And so on.  The string(s) are both descriptive to humans reading it and perhaps could be string-parsed by a program later.  Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Is the field you want to add unique per document or per json file?

Comment: Clarity:   Your description suggests each file contains only ONE document; this is why as you say `document01.json` maps to only `String01`.  You do not have more than one document in any JSON file?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Thanks Buzz.  Correct, each file holds exactly one document.  I'll update the post to make that clearer.  Thank you

Comment: More clarity:  You are providing the unique string, yes?  The external code has to invent the unique string and attach it to the one doc so that it can insert/load into mongodb and then do something else with that value?  Do you care about the size or construction of that string?  Show us 2 examples of how you want the docs to look in the final collection, complete with the key:value assignment for this mapping.

Comment: And is this a one time conversion where you can take the hit of a suboptimal but very straightforward solution using `jq` and the `bash` shell?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Thanks Buzz.  I've updated the original post with two toy examples.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Yes, this would be a one-time conversion; once the document is imported into the collection, neither the document nor string would need to be changed.

Comment: You say you want to search for `ListOfSTCharacters`:  how?    To what field do you want to assign the string `ListOfSTCharacters`?   And it seems the strings are unique but context-specific i.e. SHA2 on the file will not do.   How do you intend to create these 1000s of strings?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Good question, Buzz.  I didn't explain, but I have a large piece of software that takes a test string as input, does a lot of processing, and then generates a JSON file as output.  Sadly, the original string is NOT saved within the JSON, which would have been a huge help.  The point of my post is to use MongoDB to examine the diversity of string inputs/JSON outputs.  (My "Star Trek" themed examples may have given you the wrong impression, sorry about that.  An actual input string looks like "TX192_c29_2933_A" or something even less human-readable.)

Comment: I still don't understand where you are getting the strings from to associate with the 1000s of files.   Once we understand the mechanics of how you intend to pair a file with a particular string, the rest is easy.   It's basically `jq | mongoimport` .

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Thanks Buzz.  The strings are product codes from our company catalog.  "TX192_c29_2933_A" represents Widget 101, perhaps.  The company software takes the string as input, crunches inventory, then generates the JSON output.  So I know the input string/output JSON before I import the JSON documents into MongoDB.  But it bothers me that I can't MAP(String) ==> Document or MAP(Document) ==> String inside MongoDB.  Hence this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `jq` as a starter.

```bash
TMPF=/tmp/alldat.json

rm -f $TMPF

#  We still are not exactly sure how you intend to present a pair of your unique strings
#  and the file name to the environment but let us assume you have a simple file of filename and unique string, e.g.
#  $ cat maps.dat
#  f1.json TX192_c29_2933_A
#  f2.json TX192_c29_2933_B

#  Then this should get you going.

while IFS=' ' read -r file ustr; do
    # Add ukey as a peer field to the JSON and build up a big file
    # to import:
    jq -c ".ukey=\"$ustr\"" $file >> $TMPF
done < maps.dat
# Import en masse; more efficient than calling mongoimport 1000s of times:
mongoimport --uri 'mongodb://localhost:37017/testX' -c foo $TMPF
```

You can now query MongoDB via `ukey` e.g.:

```js
db.foo.find({ukey: 'TX192_c29_2933_A'});
```

Comment: Thanks Buzz!  I will implement and report back, much appreciated!